# Converting a string to a new format

Tags: c#, if-statement, variables, formatting

I'm running a C# app that extracts a date string in `MM/DD/YYYY` format except that when the day is less than 10, the data comes out as `MM/D/YYYY`. (i.e: it extracts `2/4/2020`.. not `2/04/2020`).

I store the data in a `strDateExtracted` variable.

When I paste/put the data the application requires me to put it in as `MMDDYYYY`

For example if I extract `2/4/2020`, the application wants me to put `02042020`.

I need to convert that string from `MM/DD/YYYY` to `MMDDYYYY` and if day is greater than 9, then `MMDYYYY` to `MM/0D/YYYY`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could start by showing the code that isn't working correctly... :)

Comment: `string result = DateTime.Parse(inputString).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Comment: You state, *"I need to convert that string from MM/DD/YYYY to MMDDYYYY and if day is greater that 9, then MMDYYYY to MM/0D/YYYY"*. In the first example, the input has forward slashes and the output doesn't. In the second example it's the other way around. Can you clarify? Does the input have forward slashes? Does the output have them as well?

Comment: Also, not sure why you'd save a `DateTime` in a `string`. That's just a formatted representation, but the object itself should be stored as a `DateTime` if you ever want to do anything with it other than display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways which I can think of.

First way, which basically converts the string to a `DateTime` and format it back to the required format:

```cs
public string GetDate(string input)
{
    return DateTime.Parse(input).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

The other way, which would be possibly the faster one, is splitting the string on your own and adding the `0` on your own:

```cs
public string GetDate(string input)
{
    var items = input.Split('/');

    if(items[0].Length == 1)
    {
        items[0] = "0" + items[0];
    }

    if(items[1].Length == 1)
    {
        items[1] = "0" + items[1];
    }

    return string.Join("/", items);
}
```

---

Note that this is all of course based on the guess, that the input and the required output are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input, which we will assume will have 8, 9, or 10 characters and will be formatted correctly, e.g.

```
12/12/2020 (10 chars)
2/12/2020 (9 chars)
12/2/2020 (9 chars)
2/2/2020 (8 chars)
```

We can create a C# 8.0 [switch expression](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/25/switch-expressions-in-c-8/) that returns the correct string using [ranges/indices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) on the input. This is, arguably, over-engineered, but might be useful to avoid allocations due to string splitting and what not.

The full program is below, and you can run it with this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/elCW99).

```
using System;

namespace Dates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "12/12/2020";
            Console.WriteLine(GetWithoutSlashes(input));
            input = "2/12/2020";
            Console.WriteLine(GetWithoutSlashes(input));
            input = "12/2/2020";
            Console.WriteLine(GetWithoutSlashes(input));
            input = "2/2/2020";
            Console.WriteLine(GetWithoutSlashes(input));

        }

        static string GetWithoutSlashes(string input)
        {
            return input.Length switch
            {
                // First two digits (month), third/fourth digits (day), last 4 digits (year)
                10 => $"{input[..2]}{input[3..5]}{input[^4..]}",

                9 => input[1] == '/'
                    // Single digit month with zero before it, double digit day, last 4 digit year
                    ? $"0{input[0]}{input[2..4]}{input[^4..]}"
                    // First two digits for month, single digit day with a zero before it, year
                    : $"{input[..2]}0{input[3]}{input[^4..]}",

                // Single digit month, day with zero before each, last 4 digit year
                8 => $"0{input[0]}0{input[2]}{input[^4..]}",

                _ => throw new ArgumentException("Bad input!", nameof(input))
            };
        }
    }
}
```